# Pointer points to a next element in array, but address is the same. How?

Tags: c++, pointers

I was asked this question in an interview. I understand that it copies the characters from a to s till it encounters the null character. So I believed that the address pointed to by the pointer a and s would also change.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
static char s[15];
static char a[] = "giviwfovnsn212";

void myfunc(char*s, char*a){
    while(*s++=*a++){
    cout<<&a<<" "<<&s<<" "<<*a<<endl;
    }
   return;
}


int main() {
    myfunc(s,a);
    cout<<a<<" "<<s;
    return 0;
}
```

But I get the following output:

```
0xbf85b7d4 0xbf85b7d0 i
0xbf85b7d4 0xbf85b7d0 v
0xbf85b7d4 0xbf85b7d0 i
0xbf85b7d4 0xbf85b7d0 w
0xbf85b7d4 0xbf85b7d0 f
0xbf85b7d4 0xbf85b7d0 o
0xbf85b7d4 0xbf85b7d0 v
0xbf85b7d4 0xbf85b7d0 n
0xbf85b7d4 0xbf85b7d0 s
0xbf85b7d4 0xbf85b7d0 n
0xbf85b7d4 0xbf85b7d0 2
0xbf85b7d4 0xbf85b7d0 1
0xbf85b7d4 0xbf85b7d0 2
0xbf85b7d4 0xbf85b7d0 
giviwfovnsn212 giviwfovnsn212
```

The addresses are all the same, how is that happening?

Comment: `&a` and `&s` are the address of the address, remove the `&` on both in the `cout` line.

Comment: You're doing something *way* too hard. Try something simple: `void f(int n) { ++n; } int main() { int a = 0; f(a); }` Make sure you understand *that* first.

Comment: I get my mistake with &a and &s . So the pointer is pointing to the end of string when copying is done. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So I believed that the address pointed to by the pointer a and s would also change.

Your reasoning is sound. The addresses *that they point to* do change.

> The addresses are all the same, how is that happening?

Because the addressof operator gives you the address *where the variable is stored*. Since the location where the pointers are stored does not change, the address that you print also doesn't change.

> When I use cout to output the strings in myfunc after the copying is done, it displays the complete string. why does that happen? Shouldn't the pointer be pointing to a location at the end of the string?

At the end of `myfunc` the pointers will be pointing one past the buffer. Accessing memory outside of allocated memory has undefined behaviour.

Comment: When I use cout to output the strings in myfunc after the copying is done, it displays the complete string. why does that happen? Shouldn't the pointer be pointing to a location at the end of the string?

Comment: @RohanAmin the pointer should, but the *address-of* the pointer doesn't change.

Answer (score 0):

The previous answer is correct, but in addition:

If you want to print out the address of s and a you'll actually need to do

cout << (int)a <<" "<< (int)s <<" " << *a << endl;

otherwise it will still be interpreted as a string - not an address.

or better still

cout << std::hex << (int)a <<" "<< std::hex << (int)s <<" " << *a << endl;

In reply to:

> When I use cout to output the strings in myfunc after the copying is done, it displays the complete string

You need to understand that your myfunc(char* s, char* a) function parameters are different variables to your 's' and 'a' global statics - and you are passing **by value** - so even though in myfunc you're are changing 's' and 'a' that does not affect 's' and 'a' at "main scope".